# Вывод изображений как у вк?

Tags: вконтакте

Здравствуйте. Как сделать вывод изображений как у вк? Есть у кого нибудь похожий алгоритм ресайза изображений для вывода?
[image]

или

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

От разработчика ВК, Дениса Ольшина, библиотека на JS: [Paver.js](https://github.com/deNULL/Paver.JS).

> Библиотека для укладки изображений (или любых других прямоугольных тайлов, допускающих масштабирование) на JavaScript.

Демо: [denull.github.io/Paver.JS](http://denull.github.io/Paver.JS)